# AVAssetWriter can merge two video files

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avassetreader

Do not tell me to use AVAssetExportSession, thank you.

I tried this, but failed.

```
for (int i =0; i < count; i++) {

        assetWriterInput = nil;
        assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];

        NSParameterAssert(assetWriterInput);
        NSParameterAssert([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput]);

        [assetWriterInput setExpectsMediaDataInRealTime:YES];
        [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
}        
[assetWriter startWriting];
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried with AVAssetExportSession and why you don't want to use it, because that's I would tell you to use.

Comment: Also, what is it exactly you want to do? Merge two video files? Are they stored on disk?

Comment: AVAssetExportSession to merge multiple files in IPHONE4 prone to failure. I do not know why

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried and what kind of failures you were getting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem seems solved, I add too much AVMutableCompositionTrack, led AVAssetExportSession there is a problem, I have only one AVMutableCompositionTrack, it worked. But there is a problem, I can not in IOS5.1.1 output AVFileTypeMPEG4 types of problems, which is why?

Answer (score 1):

The sample app that shows you how to do exactly what you're talking about is AVCompositionDebugVieweriOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCompositionDebugVieweriOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013421

I'm sure you can pare down the code to just the parts you need; but, if that's not yet where you're at with your level of understanding, let me know.

One more thing: this app not only contains the code you need, but also draws a graph of your output, showing you where you made the connection between the two clips, and any transition you may have inserted between them.